# prevent class instantization standalone, enabled from factory

Tags: php

I want to disable a class to be instantized by `new` operator, but lets suppose a `getObject` method what creates and returns an instance of it. Is it doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class C
{
    protected function __construct()
    {
    }

    public static function getObject()
    {
        return new self();
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

The code above fulfills the requirement: the class cannot be instantiated using `new`, one needs to use the factory method `getObject()` to create an object. However, the OP did not specify the reason they need such a construct.

There are several reasons such a design emerges; one of them is when the creation of objects of type `C` needs to be completed with some initialization that, for whatever reason, cannot be done in the class' constructor.

Another reason for this way of constructing objects of class `C` is the `Singleton` design pattern; which in fact is an "anti-pattern", but this is another discussion; in order to implement a Singleton, class `C` should look like this:

```
    class C    
    {
        private static $instance = NULL;

        protected function __construct()
        {
        }

        public static function getObject()
        {
            if (! isset(self::$instance)) {
                self::$instance = new self();
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }
    }
```

`Singleton` or not, because method `getObject()` is static it cannot be stubbed or mocked by the test frameworks and its original implementation have to be used. More, because it is the only way to create objects of class `C`, other classes that use this class cannot be tested in isolation.

All in all, even the construction is possible, it is not recommended. Enforcing the creation of objects of class `C` using language mechanisms made the class a nuisance for testing other classes that use it.

If the creation of objects of class `C` needs to be done by a certain method because of its complex initialization, a better way is use the `Builder` design pattern. Make it a non-static method of another class (the "builder") and instruct the programmers (using the class documentation) to not create objects of class `C` directly, using `new`. This way it does not affect the testability of other classes.

Comment: Note this returns a new `C` object on every call to `getObject()` which may not be the intended behavior for all readers.

Comment: There is no singleton restriction in the question. It just says to disallow creation using `new` and enforce the use of a factory method.

Comment: Of course. I will admit the devil is in the details. My concern is for future readers, as this question, while seemingly simple, is a slippery slope.

Comment: That's not a very useful answer anyway. There's more explanation in the comments now than in the "answer". Stack Overflow isn't CodeDump™ :}

Comment: Updated the answer; added the code for a `Singleton` class and some thoughts about using (or better said **not** using) the design requested in the question.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to disable a class to be instantized by `new` operator

A common approach is to privatize the constructor.

```
class Example {
    private function __construct() {
    }
}
```

The following would result in a fatal error.

```
$object = new Example();
```

While this will work, I would encourage you, and future readers, to review [Design Patterns in PHP](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html).

Comment: Your answer is missing the factory method. See @axiac's answer's `getObject`

Comment: @Paul Sasik, I am aware. My answer intentionally only addresses the first part of the question to encourage future readers to learn more about the implications of this pattern.